# In iOS UI Testing, how do I identify the MKUserLocation annotation?

Tags: ios, mkannotation, mkannotationview, uitest, mkuserlocation

I'm struggling to identify how I can tell that the MKMapView is showing the current user location pin in a UI Test.  This is a MKUserLocation annotation (and I've created an MKAnnotationView to use an image for the pin instead of the blue spot.)

Debugging tells me that the MKUserLocation annotation instance has a title of "My Location".  I was expecting that the following would work:

```
app.maps.element.otherElements["My Location"]
```

would return it but [that code].exists returns false.  Printing debugDescription of otherElements lists a whole set of annotations on the map but not the User Location.

Is there a different type of XCUIElement that represents the pin/annotation/annotation view that I can check for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **accessibility labels** to access your `MKAnnotationView`. In your code, retrieve your user location *annotation* and set an accessibility label for it:

```
yourAnnotation.accessibilityLabel = "labelYouWillUseToFindIt"
```

Then during your tests you can do:

```
app.maps.element.otherElements["labelYouWillUseToFindIt"]
```

Use `print(app.debugDescription)` to see if your annotation is visible and if not, force it to be accessible with:

```
yourAnnotation.isAccessibilityElement = true
```

You can read more about accessibility labels [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615181-accessibilitylabel)

Comment: Thanks Javier.  I could actually see it in the debug description once I added the accessibility label to the Annotation View.  It was actually retrievable via app.otherElements["Current Location"] rather than via app.maps....